# Partial derivative for a multivariate input

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following:

Suppose $\psi(x,t)$ is a solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger Equation with zero potential; show that $$ f(x,t)=\psi(x-ut,t)e^{ikx}e^{-i \omega t } $$ 
is also a solution, for $k$ and $\omega$ chosen in terms of $u$. The problem arises when I try to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(x-ut,t)$ in terms of  $\psi_{t}(x-ut,t)$ and  $\psi_{x}(x-ut,t)$. I've tried using the multivariate chain rule but keep going in circles. What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

Now first consider time independent schrödinger equation.(Omitting all physical constants) 
$ - \frac{\partial^2} {\partial x^2} \psi = E \psi $  Now set $E=k^2$ now solutions are of the form $e^{-ikx} $ and multiplyied with $e^{iE(k) t} $ it is a solution to time dependendent equation can be varified by pluging in.
A general solution $ \psi(x, t) =\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}  \tilde{\psi} (k) e^{-ikx}e^{iE(k) t} dk $. 
Assume $ \psi $ is of this form then show $f$ is of this form.

I assume hear all solution of equation must be of "the form" and I am not sure if it is true.